# super and __new__ confusion

Tags: python, class-method

As what I just learned, I can use `super()` this way:
`super(class, obj_of_class-or-_subclass_of_class)`

Code goes below:

```
#Case 1
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A init"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B init"
        super(B, self).__init__()  #ok, I can invoke A's __init__ successfully

#Case 2
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print "A foo"

class B(object):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print "B foo"
        super(B, cls).foo()   #ok, I can invoke A's foo successfully

#Case 3
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
      print "A new"
      return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
      print "B new"
      return super(B, cls).__new__()  #Oops, error
```

QUESTION:

In case 1 and 2, I can use super successfully without specifying the `obj` or `cls` to operate on.
But why can't I do the same for `__new__`?
Because, in case 3, if I use super that way, I got an error.
But if I use it this way:

```
super(B, cls).__new__(cls)
```

No error.

Comment: Note that `super()` returns a `super` object that proxies for a `class` object, not the `class` object itself. The two are similar but not the same.

Comment: @Amber Can you make your comment more explicit ? In my opinion it is confusing to understand what you are actually trying to say.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [Python release notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__) on overriding the `__new__` method:

> `__new__` is a **static method**, not a class method. I initially thought it
>   would have to be a class method, and that's why I added the
>   classmethod primitive. Unfortunately, with class methods, upcalls
>   don't work right in this case, so I had to make it a static method
>   with an **explicit class** as its first argument.

Since `__new__` is a static method, `super(...).__new__` returns a static method. There is no binding of `cls` to the first argument in this case. All arguments need to be supplied explicitly.